# Error on Bash Script for College Submission, No Such File or Directory

Tags: bash

I was trying to make a Bash script to facilitate my OOP Workshop submissions for college, but I'm getting a quick error.

The format for submitting is as follows:

`~profFirst.profLast/submit 244/w#/p#`

But whenever I run my script, I get the following error:

`./oopsbmt.sh: line 32: ~profFirst.profLast/submit 244/w5/p1: No such file or directory`

My script is as follows:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo "#####################################"
echo "Submit OOP WS!‍"

read -p "What Professor? (fs/ht): " SHORTPROF

if [ "$SHORTPROF" = fs ]
    then
    PROFESSOR="profF1.profL1"
elif [ "$SHORTPROF" = ht ]
    then
    PROFESSOR="profF2.profL2"
else
    echo "Professor not found."
    exit 0
fi

read -p "What Workshop Number?: " WORKSHOPNUMBER

read -p "What Part?: " PARTNUMBER

if [ -z $1 ]
    then
    DUE=""
elif [ $1 = d ]
    then
    DUE=" -due"
else
    DUE=""
fi

~${PROFESSOR}/"submit 244"/w${WORKSHOPNUMBER}/p${PARTNUMBER}"${DUE}"
```

Comment: What's your question? Please read [ask] then [edit] to clarify. If you want to ask why you're getting that error, it sounds like the file or directory doesn't exist, simple as that. Is there anything that would make you think otherwise? Also in that case, please make a [mre] including how you're running the script (so we can know what `$1` is), and the inputs (so we can know what `$PARTNUMBER` is).

Comment: @wjandrea Thanks for the answer! Location does exist, an example of what this would look like, for submitting lets say Workshop 5 Part 1 to Professor John Doe would be:

`~john.doe/submit 244/w5/p2`

If I were to run this command by itself, it works perfectly, but for some reason it doesn't work when ran from within the script.

`$1` just adds ` -due` to the end of the command, which instead of submitting just shows the due date for the assignment, an example would be:

`~john.doe/submit 244/w5/p2 -due`

which would run if the user called the command and added a `d` as a parameter.

Comment: It’s a simple typo: your quoting glues together the name of the script and the name of the file you are trying to submit. Take out the two quotes around the space after `/submit`

Comment: Note also that the `~username` can't be inside quotes if you want it to be expanded. `~username/submit 244/w5/p2` is valid unquoted. `~username/"submit" "244/w5/p2"` is valid. `"~username/submit" "244/w5/p2"` is invalid because it quotes the `~`. `"~username/submit 244/w5/p2" ` is invalid both because in quotes the tilde, and because it's munging the command and its argument together into one word.

Comment: So part of that is that _you can't reliably use `~$professor`_. That's actually a problem that would be a really good Stack Overflow question candidate; we have some that are close, but I'm not sure there's a perfect duplicate.

Comment: Does `getent passwd "$professor"` work on the operating system you're running this on?

Comment: BTW, all-caps variable names are bad form. They're reserved for names like `PATH` that changes how the operating system and shell operate; as defined by [POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html), applications should use names with at least one lower-case character to avoid overwriting names meaningful to the operating system's provided tools by mistake.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for all the responses! I changed the variable names to lowercase. Running `getent passwd` does work! I have removed the quotes, but if I do, I get an error when the script gets executed, it just runs up to the space and gives me `~username/submit: No such file or directory`

Comment: Okay, if `getent passwd` works, you can read its output to get the professor's home directory in a way that's less hacky than the `eval` in my current answer :)

Comment: (hint: `IFS=: read username _ uid gid humanname homedir shell < <(getent passwd "$professor")` will populate all the variables thus named)

Answer (score 1):

- Tilde expansions happen early in the parsing process, *before* parameter expansions take place; `~${username}` doesn't work.
- You can't quote a command together with its arguments; they should be two separate words.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "#####################################"
echo "Submit OOP WS!‍"

read -p "What Professor? (fs/ht): " shortprof

case $shortprof in
  fs) professor="profF1.profL1" ;;
  ht) professor="profF2.profL2" ;;
  *)  echo "Professor not found."; exit 1 ;;
esac

read -r -p "What Workshop Number?: " workshop_number
read -p "What Part?: " part_number

extra_args=( )
[[ $1 = d ]] && extra_args+=( -due )

printf -v prof_cd_cmd 'cd ~%q' "$professor"
prof_dir=$(eval "$prof_cd_cmd" && pwd) || exit

exec "$prof_dir/submit" "244/w${workshop_number}/p${part_number}" "${extra_args[@]}"
```